# Automatically assign a bunch of objects to another object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Terrible title, but didn't know how else to phrase this.

The situation is this:

I have an app where users can signup and get activities for their kids to do. Accordingly, there is a User model, Child model, and Activity model.

Users have many children, and children have a relationship to activities through a ChildActivity model. Users can mark off activities their children have completed.

When users create a child, I want 10 activities which are within the child's age range to automatically be assigned to that child. Activities have a min age and max age, and children have a set age.

What I don't know is the best way to do the automatic assignment of activities to a child when the child is created.

Any guidance you have here would be much appreciated. Including my code below for reference.

*models/child.rb*

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :user

has_many :child_activities
has_many :activities, through: :child_activities, class_name: 'Activity'

end
```

*user.rb*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
 has_many :children, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, allow_destroy: true
end
```

*controllers/children_controller.rb*

```
class ChildrenController < ApplicationController

 def new
    @user = current_user.find(params[:user_id])
    @child = Child.new
 end

 def create
    @child = current_user.children.build(child_params)
  if @child.save
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path, notice: "You have added a child!")
  else
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path, notice: "Something went wrong — please try again.")
  end 
end

def update
    if @child.update(child_params)
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
  else
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
  end 
end

private

    def child_params
        params.require(:child).permit(:name, :age, :user_id, :created_at, :updated_at)
    end

end
```

*controllers/registrations_controller.rb*

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.children.build
end

private

def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
 root_path
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being easier than I thought. Just added a method to my Child model. Code below.

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
acts_as_voter
belongs_to :user
after_save :add_activities

has_many :child_activities
has_many :activities, through: :child_activities, class_name: 'Activity'

has_many :completions
has_many :completed_activities, :through => :completions, :source => :completable, :source_type => "Activity"

private

def add_activities
    @activities = Activity.where('min_age <= ? AND max_age >= ?', self.age, self.age) 
    @activities.each do |activity|
        self.child_activities.create(:activity_id => activity.id)
    end
end

end
```